# Make a reference to a field of a foreign key in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I have the following models:

```
public class Item {
   public string ItemID {get; set;}

   public decimal AvailableQuantity {get; set;}
}

public class Element {
   public string ElementID {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Item")]
   public string ItemID { get; set; }
   public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

   public decimal Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

I want the **Quantity** field from **Element** to be always less than the **Item** that it's representing. I tried using the Foolproof data annotation:

```
[Foolproof.LessThanOrEqualTo(Item.AvailableQuantity)]
public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

but I get the following error:

```
CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Element.Item'
```

What can I do to satisfy this condition? I want to use it for data validation in form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have another problem too:

```
public class Item {
   public string ItemID {get; set;}

   public decimal AvailableQuantity {get; set;}
}

public class Element {
   public string ElementID {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Item")] // you dont have a property called Item here except from the Item 
    object which cant be used as a foreign key.
   public string ItemID { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("ItemID")] //this will work
   public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

   public decimal Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

As for data annotation Foolproof has options but i think you cant do it on these models.
Try it Creating a ViewModel so the properties comparing are in the same model;
This may work:

```
[GreaterThan("Quantity")]
```